# API for Windows RDP terminal Service for Android

Tags: android, windows, rdp

I did some research on RDP (Remote Desktop Protocol). I need to access Windows computer via Android device, is there any API working for RDP to use Terminal services of Windows via Android?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you need to use FreeRDP:
http://www.github.com/FreeRDP/FreeRDP/